# How to modify this multiple argument method to kwargs only?

Tags: python, methods, parameters, arguments, keyword-argument

```
 class SalesforceConnectionLiaison:

     def __init__(self, *, organisation_id, mongo_client):
         self.organisation_id = organisation_id
         self.mongo_client = mongo_client
         self.salesforce_manager = SalesforceConnectionManager(
             organisation_id=organisation_id, mongo_client=mongo_client)
         self.mapping_manager = UnifiedMappingManager(
             mongo_client=mongo_client, organisation_id=organisation_id)

     def connection_enable(self, automap, start_sync, connection_id, updated_by):
```

How to modify this multiple argument method to kwargs only?
Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Do you speak about `connection_enable()` or also `__init__()` ?

Comment: connection_enable(), got the answer thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your question is about `connection_enable()`.

Just use `**kwargs` that allows to receive your args as a dictionary.

Then inside the function if you want to use variables, you can use `get()`.
The advantage of `get()` is that it returns `None` if the key is not present (this arg hasn't been provided as an argument).

```py
class SalesforceConnectionLiaison:

    def connection_enable(self, **kwargs):
        automap = kwargs.get("automap")
        start_sync = kwargs.get("start_sync")
        connection_id = kwargs.get("connection_id")
        updated_by = kwargs.get("updated_by")
```